# Why is Ona'as Devarim not in Hilchos De'os?

Tags: rambam, middos-character-traits, bein-adam-lachavero

The Rambam places most of the laws regarding social, interpersonal relationships (such as the prohibition against slander) in Hilchos De'os, but he seems to be missing an important one: ona'as devarim, the prohibition against distressing another person. While it's true that the Rambam does mention this in other places (Hil. Teshuva 7:8, Mechirah 14:12), it seems like it should be worth at least a passing mention in Hilchos De'os.

Comment: Would you be happy with an answer for why it is in Mechira with other kinds of Onaah? Or specifically why not even a passing mention in Deot?

Comment: @DoubleAA not really (to the first option); I know why it's in Mechira, but I want to know why there isn't even a passing reference in Hil. De'os (like there is in Hilchos Teshuva)

Comment: If I recall this is discussed in Introduction to the Code of Maimonides

Comment: Arguably it is included by implication in [Deios 6:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=18744&rid=149)

Comment: @mevaqesh found it, page 293. Thanks!